# String split on dynamic separator

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, packet

I am to deal with the following problem. 
I have to extract messages from a communication buffer. Sadly the communication protocol is lousy and not well-structured. The only way I came up with to distinguish packets in the buffer is an intermediate "ack" command that is transmitted by the server.

**Example:**

> [Packet1][ACK][Packet2][ACK][Packet3]

I could have used String.Split(ACK), but the separator is also not consistent. Though, there are 3 rules to identify the ack packet.

1. Starts with "AK".
2. Ends with "0" or "1".
3. Total length is 5 characters.

**Ack example:**
"AKxxy" where:
*xx: (01 to 99)

y: (0 or 1)*

I hope that there may be a regular expression that can solve my problem, but I lack the needed knowledge and time.

Is there any RegEx "expert" that may possible help me? Feel free to suggest any solution.
Thank you.

Edit:
**Example packet** (I really had to remove the packet information):
AK010CONFIDENTIALPACKET1AK011CONFIDENTIALPACKET2AK020AK011CONFIDENTIALPACKET3AK021CONFIDENTIALPACKET4AK050

Sadly, each packet in the protocol does not start or end with a specific character so I cannot distinguish them. To identify each one I have to split them using the ack packet and then perform different checks on each one.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add a few example strings and the expected outputs?

Comment: "but I lack the needed knowledge and time." And that´s why you give your work to us? That´s not how SO is supposed to work. We all have our own work and not much time. So please be so kind to try yourself and ask a question if you´re stuck at a specific point.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Indeed it seems like I am giving work to someone else, but that was not my goal. I thought that it would be an easy task for a person with deep RegEx understanding to help me. I am trying to solve this issue for a long time over the past days using complex, ugly -and ultimately incorrect- string operations, but I couldn't. I am sorry if I broke any community policy.

Comment: The greater risk/problem would be if packages could straddle the end of your buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct translation would be

```
\bAK\d{2}[01]\b
```

That is

```
\b    # a word boundary
AK    # AK literally
\d{2} # two digits
[01]  # one of 0 or 1
\b    # another word boundary
```

The expression needs to be tested though (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/UkJ0H9/1)).

Comment: Thank you! It seems with this expression I am quite close to my goal. The exact expression you suggest does not give me any results. Removing the work boundaries allowed me to identity the ack packets. I have further work with the provided expression.

Comment: Problem solved.   `var packets = Regex.Split(buffer, @"AK\d{2}[01]");`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

looking at the other answers, this has probably merely ornamental value.
The solution of @Jan and @ThymosK

```
var packets = Regex.Split(buffer, @"AK\d{2}[01]");
```

seems much more elegant.

But I think it might be nice to see how all the parsing can be moved inside the regex. Even if it is way too unreadable :P

I have designed a regex that can give you messages and delimiters as groups:

```
(?s)(AK[0-9][0-9][0,1])|((?:(?!AK[0-9][0-9][0,1]).)*)
```

It can analyze text like this:
[image]

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/489).

As usual, regexes are write only. I can hardly read this myself. But I'll try and go through it:

The first group is straightforward and simply catches your ack command:

```
(AK[0-9][0-9][0,1])
```

The second group contains a negative lookahead `(?! ... )` which matches anything not followed by the regex specified by `...`. Here we insert your `ack` syntax, so anything not followed by `ack` is matched. Then we add a single character, to extend this to actually match anything up to `ack`. 
Basically this second part asserts that we are currently not followed by `ack` and then adds a single character. This is repeated as long as possible, until we find the `ack`. I turn this into the second group.

Since I don't have C# currently, I can't wrap this in code with the C# regex engine. But python works nicely with it and offers a useful findall method, that gives you all those groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
string interim = Regex.Replace(buffer, "AK\d{2}[01]", "|");
var commands = interim.Split('|');
```

Assuming that `|` is not a valid input char. You can pick something very exotic.

Comment: Sadly most of the packets contain the char `|`, so that would cause me more trouble. Though, I could replace the RegEx with a sequence that I am sure that is not going to be send and then split the string with it.

Comment: Like I said: pick something exotic. You can use any Unicode char or when it has to stay in the ASCII range,  a control char (Tab, Esc, ...)